# C# DDD: Change Basket Item quantity if avaiable

Tags: domain-driven-design, single-responsibility-principle

I try to design per first DDD project. I have create a method in BasketItem to change te quantity of current item in my basket, the quantity can be change only if in the warehouse there are enough items.

I make this check in the application services, but i don't like because BasketItem.ChangeQuantity is a public method and anyone can call this method without check the quantity.

to prevent incorrect quantities from being entered, I would like to move the control to ChangeQuantity. Is this solution correct? Considering SOLID the method would have too many responsibilities?

Which road do you recommend?

```cs
public class Basket : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
   public long BasketId { get; protected set; }
   public long UserId { get; protected set; }

   private List<BasketItem> _basketItems;
   public virtual IReadOnlyCollection<BasketItem> BasketItems => basketItems?.ToList();
}

protected Basket() { }

public class BasketItem : Entity
{
    public Guid Guid { get; protected set; }
    public decimal Price { get; protected set; }
    public int Quantity { get; protected set; }

    public virtual Basket Basket { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; protected set; }

    protected BasketItem() { }

    public IStatusGeneric ChangeQuantity(int quantity)
    {
        var errorStatus = new StatusGenericHandler();

        //How to get avaiable quantity from WarehouseProduct?????????
        //var avaiable = Basket.Warehouse.ProductQuantityAvaiable(Product);

        if (avaiable < quantity)
        {
            var errorStatusMessage = $"There are only {avaiable} avaiable product of {Product.Code}.";
            if (productQuantityInBasket > 0)
            {
                errorStatusMessage += $"Current basket have already {productQuantityInBasket}";
            }
            errorStatus.AddError(errorStatusMessage);
            return errorStatus;
        }

        haveProduct.ChangeQuantity(quantity);
        return errorStatus;
    }

}

public class Warehouse : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public long WarehouseId { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; protected set; }

    private List<WarehouseProduct> _warehouseProducts;
    public virtual IReadOnlyCollection<WarehouseProduct> WarehouseProducts => _warehouseProducts?.ToList(); 
}

public class WarehouseProduct : Entity
{
    public Guid Guid { get; protected set; }
    public int Quantity { get; protected set; }

    public virtual Warehouse Warehouse { get; protected set; } 
    public virtual Product Product { get; protected set; } 

    private WarehouseProduct() { }

    public void ChangeQuantity(int deltaQuantity)
    {
        Quantity += deltaQuantity;
    }
}
```

The second solution is to bring the Warehouse into the Basketball. This way I can access all the elements of the warehouse to find the available quantity. This would also allow me to associate basketball with a specific warehouse, so that I can manage multiple warehouses

```cs
public class Basket : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public long BasketId { get; protected set; }
    public long UserId { get; protected set; }
    public Warehouse Warehouse { get; protected set; }

    private List<BasketItem> _basketItems;
    public virtual IReadOnlyCollection<BasketItem> BasketItems => _basketItems?.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about passing in a service that allows the AR to query the inventory of a given item as as in `basket.changeItemQuantity(itemId, quantity, inventoryService)`?

Some people dislike that style and will prefer resolving the inventory in the application service and then provide it to the AR e.g. `basket.changeItemQuantity(itemId, qty, qtyOnHand)`. I prefer the first approach here, even though unit testing would be is slightly more involved.

A third approach would be to implement a domain service to orchestrate the logic. You'd extract the domain logic you currently have in your application service to that domain service and delegate the use case processing from the app service to the domain one. It's probably overkill for just that rule and would just drive you towards an anemic model.

A few remarks about your design proposals:

- You should not hand out non-root entities references. The Basket should provide the interface for changing quantities.
- The second proposal to hold a reference to a Warehouse AR from the Basket AR would also violate AR design rules: ARs should only reference other ARs by id. Thats helps keeping the ARs small and focused and lets the developer see what data is truly owned and protected by every AR. You will also be less tempted to change both ARs in the same transaction.
- Data referenced from outside an AR boundary is to be considered stale. You may want to explore scenarios where you'd add items to the basket only to find out a few moments later that the inventory was already depleted. What do you do then? Thinking about these scenarios will guide you towards a more business-oriented model that can deal with such intricacies rather than trying to make everything a strongly consistent invariant an end up with an impractical model misaligned with the domain needs.

Comment: You also answered my next question, that is, in terms of microservice and bounded context, if it was correct as I had created the Entities, because bringing other entities inside does not allow me to divide the context. Thank you very much

Comment: A final thought regarding "Data referenced from outside an AR boundary is to be considered stale."
I could also change the quantity of my item and create a domain event that will be managed by the warehouse and that will take care (in the same transaction) to check the quantity and if so to proceed or otherwise generate another event that will be managed by the cart to restore the previous quantity in the cart?

Comment: In a toy system you could very well update both, the basket and warehouse in the same transaction, either using synchronous events or a domain service and that would strongly protect against buying what's unavailable. However in practice you'd have to use pessimistic locking on the warehouse and therefore serialize all transactions which would harm scalability (or retry on optimistic locking error). Furthermore in real life the warehouse is most likely another system living on different servers with different infrastructure tech.

Comment: That's where you may introduce sagas to coordinate a process involving many ARs in various contexts.

Comment: About the second proposal, "ARs should only reference other ARs by id.". In my model i have the aggregate root Product and the aggreggate root Category. My product have an public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }. Considering that products and categories will always be in the same bounded context can it be fine? Because otherwise you will lose some the advantages offered by EF Core

Comment: Well, it would be considered persistence infrastructure leaking, but sometimes you must be practical. When you can and it makes sense try to extract that pollution to a layer supertype. You can also try to introduce a layer-oriented interface such as `IHaveParent<Category>`. Just make sure to never mutate the Category AR through Product and that it feels clear that Category doesn't belong to Product's boundary. Also, il you have that relationship to simplify queries, note that queries usually dont go through the domain model at all.

Answer (score 0):

OK, great DDD question. And some really interesting discussions.

I'm currently in the process of writing a Shop application - so this is a really useful question for me and my team.

I'll start by saying, you should be discussing this with the Warehouse, Sales and management teams, to get a good understanding of the scenarios.  If 2 sales people call the warehouse at the same time, and ask about current stock and whether they can sell - makes all the difference to your implementation.

### Technical / Code

General Discussion

1. If an item is added to a Basket - should the stock actually be reduced?  Consider you have 5 items in stock. 5 baskets have 1 item; can no-one else add this item to their basket - what if they're actually ready to buy - how stale do the existing baskets have to be?
   Consider: 5 items left, 5 items added to Basket 1 month ago. Should this block a ready to buy user?

Here is my technical view (happy to discuss further)...
@plalx has some great ideas, in my view its actually somewhere between.

You really just want to ask one question - Can I add this item at this quantity to this basket...

```cs
Basket basket = _basketStore.Get(1);
basket.ChangeQuantity(item, quantity, availability);
```

// Defintions

```cs
public interface IAvailabilityProcessor {
  bool AvailableForBasket(item, quantity);
}
```

```cs
public class Basket {
  public void ChangeQuantity (Item item, int quantity, IAvailabilityProcessor processor) {
     var canBeAdded = processor.AvailableForBasket(item, quantity);

     if (canBeAdded) {
        this.Add(item, quantity);
     }
}
```

I could and generally do, spend hours talking about the exact implementations of these things, but I leave it like this for now - please feed back or ask questions

Comment: It's definitely a good idea to apply the ISP and make the interface as focused as possible. That's always what I do when passing services to ARs.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is not doing it. I would follow mrdnk's advice of asking the stakeholders and try to understand well the business reasons behind the feature.

One of the indicators that there are possible business implications that are not covered in this feature is the possibility of race conditions. No matter how you implement this check, you'll get race conditions eventually, especially during business times (and [race conditions don't exist](http://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/)): You have 1 item in the warehouse, you get 100 requests in parallel and 100 users manage to put that item in the basket. Or you have one Ferrari in the warehouse, one kid playing puts it the basket and a real buyer can't buy it because there's no stock. Or there's stock, only one buyer who puts it in the basket, but the warehouse does inventory and readjusts the inventory mismatches and you don't have enough items anymore. And the list goes on...

Another smell I see is the need for calling the Warehouse from the Basket. These are very likely in two separate bounded contexts and ideally, you don't want to couple them so much.

Obviously every domain is different and as mentioned before, you'll have to figure this out with the stakeholders. How do they resolve it "in real life"? If this is an existing business, it must have happened already more than once that orders come in and there's no stock. How do they handle it?

One way of handling this scenario in online shops is to simply not try to stop a customer from buying based on stock. Especially not in the basket anyway. Imagine Amazon, while you keep an item in the basket for a couple of days, the stock might change hundreds even in multiple warehouses.

Instead, you can show the (stale) stock amount to the user in the product view and in the basket view. For example, near the "Add to Basket" button you can show "3 items in stock" or "Low Stock". You don't need to couple the basket with the Warehouse to implement this. The UI can directly call the warehouse when loading the page to get the stock of the items that it's displaying.

Once, eventually, an order is placed, the warehouse can lock the items for that order, order more items, notify the customer that there'll be a delay, etc.

Comment: In terms of design, I really like it, as regards the answer to my specific problem "Change Basket Item quantity if avaiable" the @plax solution is excellent. By implementing the CQRS with Event Sourcing I could have a view with the generic quantity of products (low, medium and high availability), in order to have a faster and less demanding reading in the warehouse during basket operations. During the Order process I could transfer the excellent plax solution by implementing an InventoryService

Comment: I understand that from a technical point of view, @plax's is a good solution to what you want to do and it's fair that you mark it as the correct solution. But note that from a DDD point of view, I don't think it is. IMO, in DDD you solve problems by designing your software based on your domain, not by applying technical solutions. There are some smells that indicate that your boundaries or aggregates are wrong, like when you have to call another BC or when you need transactions across aggregates. When I encounter these smells, even if I can solve them technically, I try to fix the root cause.

Comment: @FrancescCastells From what I understood it was just a toy project so focusing on the domain was a bit out of scope, but I completely agree with you and I'm hinting at what you`re saying in the very last bullet point.

Comment: @plalx that's fair enough, although technically it's not a DDD question then.

Comment: @FrancescCastells Tactical patterns are also part of DDD, although not considered as important as strategic ones these days, so I wouldn't necessarily say it's not, but I get your point... trying to DDD without a real project is often pointless as you won't ever crunch knowledge and make breakthroughs.